# Functor's instance variable is not kept between consecutive calls to generate_n

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I am using the following struct as an input to STL's `generate_n` algorithm:

```
struct GenerateNumber {     
    GenerateNumber () : i(0) {}
    int operator () (void) {        
        return  i++;
    }
private:
    int i;
};
```

An example to the code that uses this functor is:

```
std::vector <int> v1 (3);
std::vector <int> v2 (3);
GenerateNumber generateNumber;
std::generate_n (v1.begin (), 3, generateNumber);
std::generate_n (v2.begin (), 3, generateNumber);
```

However, the result is that both `v1` and `v2` contain `{0,1,2}`, instead of `v2` to contain `{3,4,5}`. I have verified with a breakpoint that the `GenerateNumber`'s constructor is called only once (I know it doesn't make sense that the constructor is called more then once, but I checked it anyway).

I know I can solve this by making `i` static, but I don't understand this behavior. How come the value of `i` is not kept between consecutive calls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The generator object is copied when passed to `generate_n`. Try using `std::ref`, i.e.

```
std::generate_n(v1.begin(), 3, std::ref(generateNumber));
std::generate_n(v2.begin(), 3, std::ref(generateNumber));
```

**Edit:** Note that `std::ref` is only available in C++11. It was introduced in TR1 as `std::tr1::ref`, and is also available in boost as `boost::ref`.

Comment: You should mention that `std::ref` is C++11 (although it's also mentioned in TR1).

Comment: I will probably have to stick with the `static` solution, since I need my code to compile both in VS2010 (which implements c++11) and GCC 4.4 (which doesn't). However, just for the completeness, when I use your suggestion I get the following compile error: `error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\algorithm 1581`

Comment: @LucDanton: Thanks for the note. Sometimes I forget, that there was a time before C++11.

Comment: @ItamarKatz I added a solution that *could* work for you without resorting to statics.

Comment: Seems the compiler can't find `std::tr1::ref` - it does find `std::tr1::reference_wrapper`, but I still get the same compiling error. I will keep trying.

Comment: @ItamarKatz: Don't spend too much time on this solution. It works on GCC-4.7 with `std::ref`. It doesn't work with `std::tr1::ref` - most likely because it depends on some C++11 language feature. Apparently, it also doesn't work with `boost::ref`. If you can't use C++11, maybe you can build your own `reference_wrapper` for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

[std::generate_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) takes the functor by value, that is, it makes a copy of it. It could be that you didn't check that the *copy constructor* was being called.

In the absence of `std::ref`, and if your problem is localised as in your example, you could modify your functor to take a reference to a counter set in the scope of the calls to `std::generate_n`:

```
struct GenerateNumber {     
    GenerateNumber (int& i) : struct GenerateNumber {     
    GenerateNumber () : i(0) {}
    int operator () (void) {        
        return  i++;
    }
private:
    int& i;
};

int main() {
  int counter = 0;
  std::vector <int> v1 (3);
  std::vector <int> v2 (3);
  GenerateNumber generateNumber(counter);
  std::generate_n (v1.begin (), 3, generateNumber);
  std::generate_n (v2.begin (), 3, generateNumber);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant solution.